# Memory management of container classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've made a container class to store a single tweet. Its initialized by passing in a dictionary object which is a single tweet.

I then store an array of these 'tweets' which I process through to display in a table.

The project is now finished and I am reviewing everything at the moment and I was wondering is there a better way to do this in the future. Is the memory handled correctly. I declare the string member vars with 'copy' and later in the dealloc I use a 'release' rather than just setting them to 'nil'.

Is my init ok or could that be improved?

Tweet.h
    #import

```
@interface Tweet : NSObject 
{
NSString * _userName;
NSString * _tweetText;
NSString * _tweetURL;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * userName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * tweetText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * tweetURL;

- (id) initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)productsDictionary; 

@end
```

Tweet.m
    @implementation Tweet

```
@synthesize userName = _userName;
@synthesize tweetText = _tweetText;
@synthesize tweetURL = _tweetURL;

- (id) initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)productsDictionary 
{
NSDictionary *aDict = [productsDictionary objectForKey:@"user"];
self.userName = [aDict objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
self.tweetText = [productsDictionary objectForKey:@"text"];

NSRange match;
match = [self.tweetText rangeOfString: @"http://"];
if (match.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSString *substring = [self.tweetText substringFromIndex:match.location];
    NSRange match2 = [substring rangeOfString: @" "];

    if (match2.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        self.tweetURL = substring;
    }
    else
    {
        self.tweetURL = [substring substringToIndex:match2.location];
    }
}
else 
{
    self.tweetURL = nil;
}

return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
[self.tweetText release];
[self.tweetURL release];
[self.userName release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Many Thanks,
Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first sight, I see no inherent flaws here. That looks fine. I would prefer to do:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    [_tweetText release];
    [_tweetURL release];
    [_userName release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

But what you do is good as well.

Comment: Hi Rudy, thanks for the input. Does anything different happen between what I have done and what you suggest?  Thanks, -Code

Comment: Also would self.tweetText = nil; be ok instead of [self.tweetText release]; since the NSString objects are 'copy' rather than retain? Or am I misunderstanding how that works. I've seen people do that kind of thing before.

Comment: Rudy's version directly access references to the objects to be released. Code's version access the references through a method call. Rudy's version should be faster. I don't know if the compiler can optimize Code's version to be as fast as Rudy's, but it seems simple enough of an optimization for a complier. The method call access is fast enough that a large number of these objects must be dealloced to make a noticeable difference to the app users.

Comment: Yes, `self.TweetText = nil;` would be OK too, since the setter would release the old value of the string and set it to nil. But that is a rather indirect way to release the string, and I prefer the direct one. I do it for reasons of logic, not because mine is a teeny weeny bit faster.

Comment: Properties with the copy attribute also retain their objects. So a assigning anything to self.tweetText first releases the current object referenced by the property, then copies that thing, ending up with a reference to a new object with a retain count of one. Assigning nil does release the old object, but skips the copy and retain steps. Just releasing is faster in dealloc. Assigning nil is safer if you're clearing out an ivar, but not deallocing the whole object.

Comment: Thanks Rudy, I appreciate your advice  :)